What's the most efficient way to remove all whitespace from a python string?
I'm doing a project where I want lines of text with zero whitespace (for a cryptography project I'm doing). I have a large text file with text dumped from the internet, and I'm reading it one line at a time (this could be a part of my problem), seeing if the line is too small, and if not, cleaning the text (removing special characters and punctuation), seeing again if it's too small, and if not, removing all the whitespace from the line (specifically: space, tab, u'\xa0', and newline). Removing the whitespace is incredibly slow, whatever I try.
Cleaning up the extra characters is really efficient with this function:
combined_re = re.compile(r'[^a-z0-9?\s]+') #If I change this to r'[^a-z0-9?]+' and remove the clean_whitespace functionality, it takes 11.1 seconds to process 2_000 lines, otherwise it does so almost instantly
def clean_paragraph(paragraph):
    paragraph = paragraph.lower()
    paragraph = combined_re.sub('', paragraph)
    return paragraph

However, when I go to clean the whitespace, it takes so much longer. I've tried asking ChatGPT for advice on how to write more efficient ways of doing it, plus some googling, but nothing is very quick. This stackoverflow post (Remove all whitespace in a string) lists a lot of great ideas, but I don't just want a way to remove whitespace (I have plenty listed below, and in the above linked-to question), I want a more efficient way to remove whitespace.
Following is what I've tried so far, and how quickly they handled reading in 2,000 cleaned lines of text (I'm aware not all of these do exactly the same whitespace cleanup, but the main point is none of them are very fast at all):
whitespace_trans = str.maketrans('', '', ' \t\v\f')
whitespace_re = re.compile(f'[\w]+')
def clean_whitespace(paragraph):
    # If I don't clean any whitespace:
        # 2_000 in 0.0 seconds
    # paragraph = paragraph.translate(whitespace_trans)
        # 2_000 in 9.8 seconds
    # paragraph = whitespace_re.sub('', paragraph)
        # 2_000 in 15.2 sec
    # paragraph = paragraph.replace(' ', '').replace(u'\xa0', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '')
        # 2_000 in 9.6 sec
    # paragraph = ''.join(c for c in paragraph if not c.isspace())
        # 2_000 in 25.6 sec
    # np_array = np.array(list(paragraph))
    # paragraph = ''.join(np_array[np.char.isalnum(np_array) | (np_array == '?')])
        # 2_000 in 1m 36 sec
    # paragraph = ''.join(c for c in paragraph if c != ' ' and c != '\t' and c != '\n' and c != u'\xa0')
        # 2_000 in 36.3 sec
    # paragraph = "".join(paragraph.split())
        # 2_000 in 10.7 sec
    return paragraph

I'm hoping to process on the order of hundreds of thousands to millions of lines like this, how can I do it in an efficient way (e.g. under a second for processing 2,000 lines)?
